# Can I combine the .load function with the document.referrer function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I want a specific `div` to be loaded from the previous page a user originated from.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div_to_be_populated").load('url #div');
});
```

In the url, how can I use the `document.referrer` function to get the url from which the user came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.load()` and `document.referrer` like this:

```
$("#div_to_be_populated").load(document.referrer + ' ' + '#divId')
```

Comment: The div is already being displayed, what I want to know is how I can make use of document.referrer in the url

Comment: I want to use document.referrer in the url parameter in this function:  .load('url  #div')

Comment: Ah I seeee @CharlesWaite , that makes sense. I updated the answer to include that